# Get all firebase data associated with a particular UID

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I have a somewhat complex Firebase setup, and I'm wondering if it's possible to get ***all*** of the data associated with a particular user in one call.

My Firebase schema looks like the following image:

[image]

So far, I've done something like this, but I think there must be a better way (like using UID to get data instead of manually parsing the entire db object)

```
export class AdminComponent {
  items: FirebaseListObservable<any[]>;
  private xyz: string;
  private firebaseList: FirebaseListObservable<any[]>;

  constructor(db: AngularFireDatabase, private router: Router, private route: ActivatedRoute) {
    this.firebaseList = db.list('/');
    this.items = this.firebaseList.subscribe(items => {
      const dbAnalytics = items[0];
      const dbBookings = items[1];
      const dbClasses = items[2];
      const dbLabs = items[3];
      const dbMachines = items[4];
      const dbPostLabs = items[5];
      const dbPreLabs = items[6];
      const dbUsers = items[7];

      for (const key in dbUsers) {
        if (dbUsers.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
         const userData = dbUsers[key];
         const userEid = userData['eid'];
         const userFullName = userData['name'];
         console.log(userEid, userFullName);
        }
      }

      for (const key in dbPostLabs) {
        if (dbPostLabs.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
          const postLabData = dbPostLabs[key];
          // Figure out why these objects are weird
        }
      }

    });

  }

}
```

All suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you would want to get just a single object from the db instead of getting all of them so you could do something like this.. Also, it would be easier to answer if I could see what the expanded data looks like.

If you already know the uid of the object you can do something like

```
this.db.database.ref(`labs/${uid}`).once('value')
```

Or if you just want the entire list of one of the objects

```
this.db.list('labs/', ref => ref.orderByChild(<object key>).equalTo(<desired key value)).valueChanges();
```

Hope this helps. If this isnt what you need, I could potentially answer better again, if the data was expanded.

Comment: Sorry, my question wasn't clear enough. I meant user, not UID. Is what I'm asking for possible?

Comment: Ok, are you saying you want a specific user object, or all of the other objects that have a corresponding user. i.e if your labs has a user id or user object attached to it?

Comment: All other objects that have a corresponding user, so the latter, but I want to get all of those objects using that user id or object. Is that possible?

Comment: Ok, i see what your saying. Ill be honest, I am not sure that you can do it all in db call, it would be more like my first siggestion with the labs and uid, you would need to do one for each object you want. I am not sure of a way to get all the corresponding objects in one call as long as the object had a userId or username attached to it